# Can a hydraulic system also serve as a battery?

Tags: internal-consistency, engineering

Hydraulics commonly use mineral oil or water to provide the pressure needed for mechanical movement, which is good but the liquid just sorta sits there not doing anything else. So I though “why not use battery fluid instead” and with the addition of a cathode and anode voila! You have a system that provides movement and energy.

**My question is painfully simple: is this a viable design choice?**

I haven’t found systems that do this which leads me to suspect that this isn’t such a good idea.

[Edit: I disapprove of comments that are basically answers. It makes it hard accept one or for answerers to answer without something being repeated. Just answer please. If you have something to comment then comment.]

Comment: You could do something like you propose, but would want to have a good reason for it. Offhand, I can’t think of any niche applications where it would be better than having an external battery. Batteries are chemical reactions, so you would also have to worry about corrosion of the materials, and for most hydraulic systems the geometry of the battery wouldn’t be very efficient.

Comment: Define "*battery fluid*".  The only common liquid electrolyte battery that comes to mind is the ~37% sulfuric acid solution used in lead-acid batteries and it's rather self evident why that isn't usable as a hydraulic working fluid.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan  --  That would be it.

Comment: Believe it or not, but there is a way to use hydraulics as an energy storage device. Although it doesn't use (often corrosive) battery fluid, instead it puts a balloon in a tube and uses hydraulic oil to compress the living daylight out of it. All that air really, ***really*** wants to expand and can be used to do some pretty impressive things... e.g. [Here's Richard Hammond using some hydraulic accumulators to hurl a whole car through the air](https://youtu.be/9aNWQyTvpSs?t=557)

Comment: @Samwise if you accept a low efficiency on a charge/discharge cycle - setting that nitrogen under pressure is going to release lots of energy as heat - without thermal insulation, a good amount of your work will be contributing to warming the weather. And I can guarantee you, you will reluctantly going to get it back at discharge time.

Comment: what benefit o you think you will get out of such a system, especially compared to something much simpler like a a normal batter and hydraulic system which would take up a lot less space than a hybrid system. After all batteries want to maximize surface area while hydraulics seek to minimize it.

Comment: the fluid you need must be : chemically active (in the battery) and chemically inert (in the hydraulic system)

Comment: While this particular approach is not practical as has been pointed out in various answers, hydraulics (combined with _heavy_ weights) can be used for energy storage. The general concept is a type of gravity battery, albeit not one which is really used in practice (most other designs are in practice significantly more efficient).

Comment: Manchester used to have a centralised power system, distributed through pipework under the streets to warehouses, mainly to operate cranes. The Museum of Science and Technology has some parts of it on display. It stored energy in a reservoir using a vertical water cylinder (several metres diameter) with about 80 tons of rock on top. Not compressible, so no heat losses. It was topped up with a steam engine as needed. It even worked with a portable handset, using a water circuit to control the main valves. It was in use from 1894 to 1972. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Hydraulic_Power

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main equirements raised against a hydraulic liquid:

1. chemically inert against the materials used for the pressure "circuit" - you don't want corrosion of the pressure tubes and pistons
2. extremely low vapor pressure - must resist forming voids filled with vapors when the pressure becomes negative (and the pressure will become negative when you squirt liquids at high velocity through narrow valves - you get those voids as cavitation)
3. a reasonable viscosity - to keep the particles resulted from friction wear in suspension.
4. reasonable large temperature range in which the substance remain liquid.

As a battery fluid, you need to:

1. have it conductive, with a good [electrochemical window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_window) and
2. *insanely clean from contaminants that throw a wrench into electrochemistry you are using for energy storage*.

The viscosity part will play a bit into losses of energy by internal friction (thus, heating), so again some extra requirement for the low vapor pressure (which is approx correlated with higher boiling temperature) and chemical stability with temperature (which more or less correlates with the large electrochemical window).

---

Now, there are some ionic liquids and deep eutectic solvents  (good candidates to that fit the bill in regards with the battery fluid part) with [low vapor pressure](https://www.mdpi.com/2305-7084/3/2/42/pdf) (PDF warning - otherwise  https://doi.org/10.3390/chemengineering3020042).
Incidentaly, the low vapor pressure is good enough to make them usable in testing [whether or not a siphon works under vacuum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F4i9M3y0ew) - spoiler: *it sucks* perfectly.

The potential problems with those ionic liquid/DES:

1. their hygroscopy - most of them are hydroscopic, which will play havoc on their vapor pressure
2. most of them really a very keen to dissolve metal oxides - which *maaay* play nasty with the chemical inertness against the elements in the pressure side, most  materials have the "stainless" trait by the formation of a compact oxide layer on they surface. I haven't look exhaustively if there are safe combinations of metals good for high pressure applications and ionic liquids/DES (otherwise I'd probably be at the patent office instead of answering on WB).

Then, *the battery function is going to be seriously impaired by the particulate in suspension and/or the dissolved oxides* - those will blow the capacity and integrity of the battery side in no time.

---

The last problem stay at the fundamental side of your question is "multifunctionality". It involves a good amount of compromises and extra fluff to "just make it work" that you will get to sacrifice performance in all the functions that you put together. To illustrate, think at a smartphones:

1. mediocre as a computation device - we're still using computers for anything serious
2. mediocre as game platforms - we still have dedicated gaming consoles
3. mediocre cameras - you haven't seen a movie in theaters filmed with smart phones
4. mediocre communication channels - just go into areas without coverage to convince yourself

In the case of "battery cum hydraulic device" - what do you want the most? Is it

1. to self power - and thus spare as much fluid as possible to coat your insane electrode area for power; *or*
2. to reduce the complexity of your pressure side of the hydraulics - thus forget filters that keep the electrolyte clean and require the lowers amount of fluid to move around?

If you get a way that can work both, you'll get something that's good for all and excelling in nothing. This is not to be sneezed at, there will be a lot of applications where good enough is... well... good enough.

Comment: "you haven't seen a movie in theaters filmed with smart phones" Actually you might have. It's not common, and they aren't big budget movies, but they do exist.